# Typescript InversifyJS - How to set variable value from maint.ts and get the value from a controller

Tags: javascript, typescript, inversifyjs

I am new to Typescript and InversifyJS. What I am trying to achieve is to share variable value across multiple files. I am setting the value on the server startup on main.ts and I am trying to fetch that value from a controller. What I did is I created a @injectable service file

service.ts

```
 import { injectable } from 'inversify';

    @injectable()
    export class SetGetService  {

        private _client : any;

        get () : any {
            return this._client;
        }

        set (client: any) {
            this._client = client;
        }                                                                           
  }
```

I am able to set the value from main.ts, but after calling the SetGetService on other files, it was undefined or empty. It seems like it was being reset or cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following in the `main.ts` file:

```
const client = new Client();
container.bind<Client>("Client").toConstantValue(client);
```

Then in the service:

```
import { injectable, inject } from 'inversify';

@injectable()
export class SetGetService  {

    @inject("Client") private _client: Client;

    get () : any {
        return this._client;
    }

    set (client: any) {
        this._client = client;
    }                                                                           
}
```

If the client is a DB client and its initialization is async you might want to use the following:

```
// ioc_modules.ts

const asyncModule = new AsyncContainerModule(async (bind) => {
    const client = await Client.getConnection();
    bind<Client>("Client").toConstantValue(client);
});

// main.ts

(async () => {
    await container.loadAsync(asyncModule);
})()
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for the answer, what does the "Client" contains?

Comment: "Client" is just a string used as ID, in TypeScript IDs cannot be interfaces because interfaces are removed from the code during the compilation, so they are not available at runtime. You can use a string a class or a symbol as ID.

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay. It says cannot find name "Client"?

Comment: This is sad state of things. Because as soon as you call `loadAsync` it will create a DB connection. Which misses the point of lazy initialization of a DI system. With the same result one can  write `bind("Client").toConstantValue(await Client.getConnection());` and avoid `AsyncContainerModule` abstraction altogether